# Finding the number of cells with strings containing a particular character

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know how many cells in each row contain strings with a particular character.  For example:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,'abc','ace'],'b':['aa','bb','cc',5],'c':['zzz','byy','xxx','wwb']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=['m','n','o','p'])
df

    a   b   c
m   1   aa  zzz
n   2   bb  byy
o   abc cc  xxx
p   ace 5   wwb
```

I want to know the number of cells in each row that contain a "b":

```
    a   b   c   Count
m   1   aa  zzz 0
n   2   bb  byy 2
o   abc cc  xxx 1
p   ace 5   wwb 1
```

`str.contains` works on Series, not DataFrames. I could step through the index and do something like

```
df.loc['m','Count'] = df.loc['m'].str.contains('b').sum()
```

but it seems like there should be a much simpler solution that I'm missing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [60]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('b')).sum(1)
Out[60]:
m    0.0
n    2.0
o    1.0
p    1.0
dtype: float64
```

or

```
In [57]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('b').sum(), axis=1)
Out[57]:
m    0
n    2
o    1
p    1
dtype: int64
```

to count how many `b` has each row:

```
In [50]: df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.count('b')
Out[50]:
m    0
n    3
o    1
p    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using applymap:

```
df['Count'] = np.sum(df.applymap(lambda x: 'b' in str(x)),1)

df
Out[99]: 
     a   b    c  Count
m    1  aa  zzz      0
n    2  bb  byy      2
o  abc  cc  xxx      1
p  ace   5  wwb      1
```